# Mouse pointer (touchpad) getting stuck often in 12.04

Tags: mouse, touchpad

In my Ubuntu 12.04, my mouse pointer gets stuck often. I'm talking about the touchpad and not the external mouse. The first thought would be to check whether we have given the option to lock the touchpad while typing. But, my pointer (touchpad) gets stuck simply often. The slightest of deductions I have been able to make is that this happens sometimes just after using the touchpad scrolling.

Can this problem be rectified or should it be reported as a bug?

Comment: You should first check which touchpad hardware you have. Is it synaptics ? Then try some other desktop environments like unity, xfce etc and see how your touchpad respond to them. If its the same `xorg-xserver-input-synaptics` is the driver package of the touchpad if its synaptics. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics see here for more information on touchpads

Comment: I believe it is a bug (and I think I've seen it too, but haven't reported it). To report the bug please see http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been reported as a bug. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/991707

Answer (score 29):

I had a similar problem, I can still scroll and click, but the cursor is stuck in one place on the screen. Dropping down to a lower run level (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) and back (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>) seems given me control of my mouse again.

Thank you for reporting this as a bug.