# How to find out the name desktop manager package running on my ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: desktop-environments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine what window manager or desktop is running?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72549/determine-what-window-manager-or-desktop-is-running)

I had an issue with my mouse pointer (touchpad) getting stuck frequently. In order to report that as a bug, I wanted to know which package my mouse pointer comes under. I assumed that it will be in the desktop manager package. Now the problem is, how can I know the package name of the desktop manager I'm running? Or rather, how can I know which desktop manager I'm running?

Comment: basically I run `env | grep XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` . AFAIK mouse pointers as well as touchpads may come under `xserver-xorg`

Comment: Thanks. I figured out I'm using GNOME with the command you mentioned. However, as for xserver-xorg, ubuntu-bug is not letting me file a bug using it.

Comment: Basically I donot know what you are trying to do. You should see some workarounds for touchpads in this site ? And you should report bug to respective package if you know it.

Comment: Well, this : http://askubuntu.com/questions/128265/mouse-pointer-touchpad-getting-stuck-often-in-12-04 was my problem. So I was trying to file a bug in that regard. So I wanted to know who is responsible for the mouse pointer. That is how I came to this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
env | grep XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
```

Answer by https://askubuntu.com/users/1543/sagarchalise